# How to prove brand preference?

Tags: distributions, marketing

Real Case: 
We have survey data on which of 6 brands is preferred by customers in each of 4 different product usage situations. Our customer segment is well defined and we think we have a representative sample. 
How do we prove the brand with the highest number of expressed preferences in each usage situation is actually the customer segment's preferred brand? Esp. if Brand A is just marginally more preferred than Brand B in a specific usage situation?

Comment: Can you explain what kind of data you have a bit more?  For example, how many customers?  What do you mean by "Our customer segment is well defined"?  How is it measured?

Comment: I think your situation is sufficiently clear: you have a representative sample of a well-defined population. But I wonder whether you are asking the right question about it. What is the point of "proving" anything, *especially when a proof is impossible due to sampling variation*? What you might want to focus on are the risks associated with acting as if the most preferred brand in the sample really is the most preferred in the population. What would those risks be? What would you lose if you are wrong about acting on that conclusion?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Our customer segment is a specific group of healthcare professionals in one country. We estimate the total population in the country is 450. We surveyed 75 of them to ask which brand they prefer in each of 4 situations (one answer possible). There are 4-6 brands available in each situation. They each gave us 4 answers, therefore. We'd like to make a marketing claim based on their expressed product preference for brand A in situations 1, 2, 3, 4 or combinations thereof.